# Solve transcendental equation involving a built-in function

Tags: equation-solving, prime-numbers, integer-sequence, implicit

How can I solve an equation of the following form?

$$x = 10+\mathrm{\mathbf{PrimePi}[x]}$$

where $x$ is an integer. I am using **`Solve`** but am getting the following error:

> $RecursionLimit::reclim2 Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during
>   evaluation of PrimePi[x]

It is the first time I attempt to do this type of task in Mathematica so I could be missing something very elemental.

Comment: You're probably using `=` ([assignment](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html)) instead of `==` ([equality](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html)).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, at first I did that and I think the message error was the same, but then corrected it and happened this. The answer below solved it, though I end up using a "while" loop to solve it iteratively, which happened to be much much quicker (not sure why) - and which did not require to specify an upper bound for `x`.

Comment: The reason why the problem didn't go away after you changed `=` to `==` was probably that you did not clear/quit the kernel, and so the previous definition was still lingering in the background (Mathematica doesn't forget anything unless you tell it to). With `?x` you can find out what definitions are associated with `x`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Solve[{0 < x < 1000 && x == 10 + PrimePi[x]}, x, Integers]

(*   {{x -> 16}, {x -> 17}}   *)
```